# DDD & Event Sourcing: expiration as specification or command?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

**Background**

I'm trying to apply ddd and event sourcing to part of my project.

It is an auction application.

- `Customer` registers `Item` and `Auction` is `STARTED` when an administrator `approves` the `Item`.
- `Auction` has `duration` which allows the `Bidder` to `Bid` within the `duration`.
- `Auction` is considered `ENDED` after that `duration` and `Bidder` cannot bid.
- `Auction` is also `ENDED` when `maximum bids limit` is encountered even if the `duration` has not passed.
- `Customer` can `select` one `Bid` within the `duration` and `5 days after the duration ends`.
- After that, we consider the `Auction` `EXPIRED` and the `Customer` cannot `select` a `Bid`.

Application requirements:

- `Bidder` should be able to query biddable auctions.
- Should send notifications for `ended` and `expired` auctions only once.

To summarize, I defined my classic DDD domain models:

Entities: `Auction`, `Bid`, `Customer`, `Administrator`, `Bidder`

Value Objects: `AuctionStatus` (`STARTED`, `ENDED`, `EXPIRED`, `SELECTED`)

Aggregate roots: `Auction`, `Customer`, `Bidder`, `Administrator`

---

**Problem**

The problem is that I'm not sure wether I should

A) define an specification like `AuctionEndedSpecification` and use it to query and judge the status and constraint actions.

or

B) consider `EndAuction` as an command and put simple attribute `status` in `Auction`

tricky part of A: To judge wether an auction is expired or ended, I need the current time and this makes the code harder to implement. And I think it might be harder to implement the query side.

tricky part of B: Auction ends for multiple reasons (when duration has passed, when maximum bids limit encountered). I learned that it is not a good practice to let an event trigger another one. But in this case, `BidAdded` event might trigger `AuctionEnded` event. Also, if I manage expiration with scheduled tasks it feels like my domain model suppose the simplicity of read side which is highly related to the application requirements.

If you've gone through similar problems, please help me with your experience.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Auction aggregate's state is clearly can be calculated from events without any additional event. Both at write-side and read-side.

Reasons why you still might want to add AuctionEnded events are:

- rules of auction endind are likely to change in the future, an then your calculation logic can became wery complex.
- you have an external service that doesnt want to calculate auction end state by itself.
- there is a general advice that your aggregate's event stream should be readable by domain expert. I think I would like to see "AuctionEnded" mark in such a stream.

If you decide to product AuctionEnded events, you'll need Saga/ProcessManager to issue an "EndAuction" command at right time.

Answer (score 0):

> To judge whether an auction is expired or ended, I need the current time and this makes the code harder to implement.

I call your attention to the writing of [John Carmack](https://github.com/ESWAT/john-carmack-plan-archive/blob/master/by_day/johnc_plan_19981014.txt)

> If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do - it is an important concept

I'd add as clarification that it is in put the *domain model*; it's not usually necessary to push your clock outside of the application boundary.

One key idea in choosing which approach to take - is the domain model the authority for deciding when an auction ends, or is it just keeping track of decisions made elsewhere?

Your first approach is aligned with the idea that the model is the authority; the application tells the model what time it is, the model decides whether or not to end the auction.

Your second approach is aligned with the idea that the model is merely bookkeeping - "end auction" coming from outside of *this* model.

Either approach can be the "correct", depending on what you are building.

Given the rest of your description, I think you are trying to build a solution of the first type, so you should be thinking in terms of telling the domain model what time it is, and letting the model decide whether or not that means the auction is over.

Warning: getting the *plumbing* right can be a pain: how does the application know *which* auctions need the time?  Does the schedule persist when the application is restarted? and so on.